# Object does not support property or method addClass in IE

Tags: jquery

I am trying to key up down event in DIV.
key up down is working.But I got the error that object does not support property or method addClass.
My code as below:

```
var $activeslide = $('.display_box.active');
var targetslide = null;

if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    if ($activeslide.next('.display_box').length) {
        targetslide = $activeslide.next('.display_box');
    } else {
        $('.display_box').first().addClass('active');
        targetslide = $('.display_box:first');
    }
}

if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    if ($activeslide.prev('.display_box').length) {
        targetslide = $activeslide.prev('.display_box');
    } else {
        targetslide = $('.display_box:last');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    alert($('.active.display_box').text());
}
targetslide.addClass('active');
$activeslide.removeClass('active');
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug your problem? Have you tried logging what the value of `targetslide` is prior to the `addClass` jQuery method?

Comment: I want to do addclass in targetslide at the end.

Comment: I understand the intent. I was attempting to gather more information on approaches you've taken to try to debug the problem yourself as a means of arriving to the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `keyCode` isn't 40, 38, or 13, you never set `targetslide` to an element. You need to check for this:

```
if (targetslide) {
    targetslide.addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar ! it is working well. I am very new. I have some other issue same as above. I will post soon. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I hope you plan on trying to figure it out yourself using the Javascript debugger. You should not depend on SO as a replacement for thinking and debugging, it should be a last resort once all else fails.

Comment: Yes. I was trying to debug it. I was stuck in this issue and I did not know it need to check. Thank for your help.

Comment: So you put a breakpoint on that line, and check the value of the variable. Isn't that normal debugging procedure?

Comment: If you don't know how to set a breakpoint, http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820